# INDEX MATCH in Matrix returns non-existing value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using INDEX MATCH to return a value in a matrix returns a non-existing value (0 in my case).
Please see the formula and data below:

**Formula (Cell J2)**

*this has been dragged to the bottom*

```
=INDEX($B$2:$F$7;VERGELIJKEN($H2;$A:$A;0);VERGELIJKEN($I2;$B$1:$F$1;0))
```

**Data**

[image: Data belonging to this question, incl. it's return values]

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the whole table including headers, and you need to match to explicit ranges too. Also I changed semicolons to commas for Excel, I'm not sure if you're able to use semicolons in other software:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$7,MATCH($H2,$A$1:$A$7,0),MATCH($I2,$A$1:$F$1,0))
```

Comment: FYI, some other countries' Excel versions use semicolons, where some use commas. Looks like VERGELIJKEN is Dutch.

Comment: Gotcha, that's interesting.